# How to pass a variable to getJSON callback function on success

Tags: jquery

I have this example code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("http://someapi", { "one": two }, function (result) {
        array[i].value = result.value;
    });
}
```

However the i variable in the callback function does not correspond to what one could expect.  The for loop is running pretty fast and are finished before the first callback function recieves an answer and so the i variable is somewhere in the loop or even finished and past the array boundary.

Anyway, is there some way to pass a variable to the callback function?  Something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://someapi", { "one": two }, function (result, i) {
    array[i].value = result.value;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("http://someapi", { "one": two }, (function(j) {
        return function (result) {
            array[j].value = result.value;
        };
    })(i)); // Immediate invocation is your best friend
}
```

Like that you can pass the `i` variable when you're declaring the callback (and not when it's evaluated like in your code).

Answer (score 3):

Creating an additional closure to store the current index and using that inside your actual function should do the trick, similar to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("http://someapi", {
        "one": two
    }, (function () { // added closure...
        var currentIndex = i; //...to allow declaration of additinal variables

        return function (result) {
            array[currentIndex].value = result.value; // use currentIndex here
        };
    })()); // () force immidiate execution
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EHx/) - Comparing results between not using a closure and using a closure

---

Open the DEMO and then click <kbd>Run</kbd>, watching the console outputs.

Code from DEMO:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Wihtout closure i is not always as expected.
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("#", {
        "one": 1
    }, function (result) {
        console.log('no-closure: ' + i);
    });
}

// With closure stored i (currenIndex) is in the expected order
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("#", {
        "one": 1
    }, (function () {
        var currentIndex = i;
        return function (result) {
            console.log('closure: ' + currentIndex);
        };
    })());
}
```